# How to use CalenderExtender in ContentPlaceHolder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `CalenderExtender` in my project inside in content place holder and calender extender is in a `UserControl`. This control is working in normal aspx-page but when i am dragging this control in `ContentPlaceHolder` then it is not working. Actually the `Calender` is not appearing in `textBox` below is my code which i used in my project.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Calender1.ascx.cs" Inherits="Facultymanagement.Calender1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcalender" runat="server"> 
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" 
TargetControlID="txtcalender" PopupButtonID="txtcalender"></asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.ToString() != "")
        {
            txtcalender.Text = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.ToString();
        }
    }
    public string TextBox1Value
    {

        get
        {
            return txtcalender.Text;
            // return Convert.ToString(Calendar.SelectedDate);
        }

        set { txtcalender.Text = value; }

    }       
}
```

This is the place where i am trying to access the value:

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = calender1.TextBox1Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I have edited your question. Have a look at the first paragraph if it was edited correctly, especially the part with the `UserControl`

Comment: Did you register the ajax control toolkit in the user control? Does your page or parent page have a script manager on it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find control first

```
    ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlacename");
    if (mpContentPlaceHolder1 != null)
    {
        Button btn_searsh;
        btn_searsh = (Button)mpContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("main_search");
        btn_searsh.CssClass += " " + "btn-primary";//to pass the rentpage class

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must doo something wrong.

The following code works:
WebUserControl1.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="WebUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<script runat="server">

</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" PopupButtonID="Image1">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Src="WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="WebUserControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

    </div>
        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl2" runat="server" />
        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl3" runat="server" />
        <uc1:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl4" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```